# Вставка текста с кавычками в БД MySQL.

Tags: mysql, htmlspecialchars, php, экранирование

Как можно записать текст, содеожащий кавычки в БД MySQL. Я делаю так:

```
 $status=str_replace("'",'"',$status);
 $status = htmlspecialchars(trim($status),ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");
```

Но в итоге в таблицу БД записываются преобразованные HTML-сущности. Пример:

```
<script>alert("")</script>    >>>   &lt;script&gt;alert(&quot;&quot;)&lt;/script&gt;
```

А есть ли точно такой же способ, но только чтобы в таблицу производилась запись оригинального текста? **Спасибо.**

Comment: Угу... То есть, по сути, вы хотите узнать, как обойти экранирование и сделать "не хорошее вливание" в БД? Вряд ли вы меня переубедите в обратном, но можете попробовать.

Comment: Нет, я ничего не пытаюсь взломать. Мне просто надо знать, возможно ли такое вообще?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Кавычка это служебный символ языка SQL. Она отвечает за отметку начала и конца строки. Если кавычку нужно записать как часть строки ее нужно экранировать `\"`. Кроме кавычек есть еще масса других спецсимволов и для того чтобы их можно было добавить в запрос как часть строки для параметров запроса существует экранирующая функция [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string( '"qwerty"' ); // '\"qwerty\"'
```

Comment: Окей, спасибо.Похоже, это именно то! А есть ли функция обратная данной?

Comment: stripslashes() уберет экранирование

Comment: ! Данный модуль устарел, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и удалён в PHP 7.0.0.

Comment: Да, сейчас лучше использовать PDO вместе и именованными параметрами. Ответу больше 10 лет :).